# jqgrid and server side pagination

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid, pagination

I realize there are some related questions but I couldn't find what I was looking for.  I used jqgrid many times in the past but forgot how to achieve server side pagination.

here is my javascript

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "index.php?loadData=test",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames: ["id", "eNodeB_unique", "enodeB_type", "radio_freq_mod", "macroEnbId_dec representation", "num_cells"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "id", width: 55 },
        { name: "enodeB_unique", width: 90 },
        { name: "enodeB_type", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "radio_freq_mod", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "macroEnbId_dec_rep", width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: "num_cells", width: 150, sortable: false }
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "My first grid",
    loadonce:false
});
```

and my server side code

```
public function getData($page, $limit, $sidx, $sord){

    $query_str = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl";

    $prepState = $this->DBi->prepare($query_str);             
    $result = $this->DBi->query($prepState);

    $count = $result[0]['count'];


    if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
        $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
    } else { 
        $total_pages = 0; 
    } 

    if ($page > $total_pages){
        $page = $total_pages;
    }

    $start = $limit * $page - $limit;

    if($start < 0){
        $start = 0;
    }

$query_str = "SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY {$sidx} {$sord} LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";

    $prepState = $this->DBi->prepare($query_str);             
    $result = $this->DBi->query($prepState);        

    return $result;     


}
```

if I keep $start and $limit in the query then i just get the inital ten results.  If I take those out... then my grid shows all my results.. but there is only one page available.  I have on option to click on the next page.

EDIT:

okay I realize now that I have to return this information..  I'm puzzled by the way I have to return the rows.  Was JQgrid always this way?

```
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM enodeB ORDER BY {$sidx} {$sord} LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";

    $prepState = $this->DBi->prepare($query_str);             
    $result = $this->DBi->query($prepState);        

    $finalRows = array();

    foreach($result as $row){
        $finalRows[] = array('cell'=> $row);

    }
    return array('page' => $page, 'total' => $total_pages, 'records' => $count, 'rows' => $finalRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static dynamic ToJson<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Collection, string sidx, string sord, string page, string rows, List<string> Columns)
    {
        return ToJson<T>(sidx, sord, page, rows, Collection, Columns);
    }



    private static dynamic ToJson<T>(string sidx, string sord, string page, string rows, IEnumerable<T> Collection, List<string> Columns)
    {
        page = page.NotNull("1"); rows = rows.NotNull("100"); sidx = sidx.NotNull("Id"); sord = sord.NotNull("asc");
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(rows);
        int totalRecords = Collection.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        if (!Collection.IsNull())
        {
            Collection = Collection.ToList().OrderWith(x => x.GetPropertyValue(sidx), sord).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize);
            return JsonData<T>(Collection, totalPages, page, totalRecords, Columns);
        }
        return BlankJson();
    }


    private static dynamic JsonData<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, int totalPages, string page, int totalRecords, List<string> Columns)
    {

        var colsExpr = Columns.ConvertAll<PropertyInfo>(x => Extentions.GetProperty<T>(x));
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = collection.Select(row => new { id = row.GetPropertyValue("Id") ?? Guid.NewGuid(), cell = GetValues<T>(colsExpr, row) }),
        };
        return jsonData;
    }

    public static dynamic BlankJson()
    {
        return new
        {
            total = 0,
            page = 0,
            records = 0,
            rows = "",
        };
    }

    private static string[] GetValues<T>(List<PropertyInfo> columns, T obj)
    {

        var values = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var x in columns)
            {

                var temp = x.GetValue(obj, null);
                values.Add(temp != null ? temp.ToString() : string.Empty);
            }
            return values.ToArray();
        }
        catch
        {
            return values.ToArray();
        }
    }
```